# success change source & track of video use onclick button, but the video still same

Tags: javascript, html, video

Before i start, i'm sorry if i belong is repost. But, i still not get the answer after check the previous thread.

i try to change source of video with onclick button. But, the video still same although the source has changed.

```
<video width="560" height="320" controls="controls" preload="none">
  <source id="myVideo" src="/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <track id="mySubtitle" src="/Subtitle1.srt" kind="subtitles" srclang="id" label="Indonesian" default>
</video>

<button onclick="myFunction1()">Change Video 1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Change Video 2</button>

<script>
function myFunction1() {
document.getElementById("myVideo").src = "/video2.mp4";
document.getElementById("mySubtitle").src = "/Subtitle2.srt";
}
function myFunction2() {
document.getElementById("myVideo").src = "/video3.mp4";
document.getElementById("mySubtitle").src = "/Subtitle3.srt";
}
</script>
```

The source has success changed, but video still same.
Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
function myFunction1() {
 document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", "/video2.mp4");//Set src attribute
 document.getElementById("mySubtitle").setAttribute("src", "/Subtitle2.srt");//Here too
}
function myFunction2() {
 document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", "/video3.mp4");//And here
 document.getElementById("mySubtitle").setAttribute("src", "/Subtitle3.srt");//Same
}
</script>
```

This should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `src` of the `<source>` element, it doesn't change the src of the `<video>` element. You have to call its `load` method :

```js
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("myVideo").src = "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4";
//  document.getElementById("mySubtitle").src = "/Subtitle2.srt";
  document.querySelector('video').load();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Change Video 1</button>

<video width="560" height="320" controls="controls" preload="none">
  <source id="myVideo" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <!--<track id="mySubtitle" src="/Subtitle1.srt" kind="subtitles" srclang="id" label="Indonesian" default>-->
</video>
```