# HTML: Audio file not updating when reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have an audio file called `sound.wav` that is 14 seconds long. When a user clicks a button, `sound.wav` source url is changed and `sound.wav` is reloaded and is now 7 seconds long.
However, my browser does not display the changes. Only after clicking the refresh button does it display the changes.

Here is my code:

```
  <div id="audioContainer">
    <audio id ="myAudio" controls>
      <source id = "wav_src" src="http://localhost:3000/sounds/sound.wav" type="audio/wav">
    </audio>
  </div>
//user clicks button... sound.wav's url source is changed
  document.getElementById("myAudio").load();   //code to reload the sound.wav
```

As you can see, I'm reloading the html audio element for `sound.wav` after the user presses a button. However, the sound file remains unchanged on the website, unless I hit refresh.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where is the `//code to reload the sound.wav`? Is it this `load()` function?

Comment: Are you intentionally changing the duration? Or do you have different wav files?

Comment: Since you are using a `<source>` element, you must call the `<audio>` `.load()` method after you changed your source's src.

Comment: That's a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168173/success-change-source-track-of-video-use-onclick-button-but-the-video-still-s/32176019#32176019 which doesn't have an upvoted answer...

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821915/how-to-force-the-html5-audio-tag-to-reload-a-changing-file , especially Alex P's answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the `src` of the `<source>` element, it doesn't change the `src` of the its parent MediaElement (`<audio>` or `<video>`). You have to call this MediaElement's *.load()* method :

```js
set_src.onclick = function() {
  source.src = 'http://cdn.music2ten.com/mp3/pd4u/GershwinWhiteman-RhapsodyInBluePart1.mp3';
  console.log('source src:', source.src);
  setTimeout(function(){console.log('audio src:', audio.currentSrc)});
}

load_btn.onclick = function() {
  audio.load(); // you must call this
  setTimeout(function(){console.log('audio src:', audio.currentSrc)});
};
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
  <source id="source">
</audio>
<br>
<button id="set_src">set src</button>
<button id="load_btn">load</button>
```

Of course you would normally do this in one-go:

```js
set_src.onclick = function() {
  source.src = 'http://cdn.music2ten.com/mp3/pd4u/GershwinWhiteman-RhapsodyInBluePart1.mp3';
  audio.load(); // you must call this
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
  <source id="source">
</audio>
<br>
<button id="set_src">set src</button>
```