# How do I change an html video source using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried a couple of things and didn't succeed. stackoverflow couldn't help me either. I have the following video:

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="1024" height="720" controls data-setup='{}' id="vidarea">
<source src="E:/Vids/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="vidsource"></video>
```

I wan't to change the video displayed when I click another video icon on my page using JS. I just couldn't do it. I've tried

```
const myVideo = document.getElementById('vidsource');
.
.
.
myVideo.src = 'E:/Vids/test2.mp4';
```

Comment: this can help you [changing source on html5 video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168173/success-change-source-track-of-video-use-onclick-button-but-the-video-still-s/32176019#32176019

Answer (score 0):

you can use setAttribute() to src attribute 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I've tried it before.

Answer (score 0):

Update without setAttribute, (this works with me & please check the video url), you don't need `<source>` tag here:

```
<video id="vidarea" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="1024" height="720" controls autoplay ></video>

<script> 
   var vid = document.getElementById("vidarea");
   vid.src = "E:/Vids/test2.mp4";
</script>
```

using [setAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp), here's your code:

```
document.getElementById('vidsource').setAttribute("src", "E:/Vids/test2.mp4");
```

if you need to add it on load

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('vidsource').setAttribute("src", "E:/Vids/test2.mp4"); 
};
```

if you need to add it on click

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="1024" height="720" controls 
 data-setup='{}' id="vidarea">
 <source type="video/mp4" id="vidsource"></video>    
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Add src</button>


function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('vidsource').setAttribute("src", "E:/Vids/test2.mp4"); 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I've tried it before.

Comment: I've update the answer, please check & make sure the video url is right because it works with me on w3schools testing area